# Download Image from External URL to Sitecore Media library

Tags: powershell-extensions

Is there a way to add (Download) an image from an external URL to the Sitecore media library directly using SPE?

Example: I want to add an image from URL (http://mySite/wp-Rad.jpg) to Sitecore media library

Comment: What examples have you found in a Google search? What scripts are you working with?

Comment: @MichaelWest
I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789516/powershell-download-files-from-url-that-does-not-include-file-name-in-the-ur/14612435 , but this add images to Directory not to Sitecore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process of uploading an image from External URL can be performed as follows:

1. Download the image to a directory.
2. Upload the image.
3. On completion, delete image from directory

Below is the script I have used to download then upload the image to a predefined Sitecore Path in the Media Library

```
function New-MediaItem{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$filePath,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$mediaPath)

    $mco = New-Object Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
    $mco.Database = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master");
    $mco.Language = [Sitecore.Globalization.Language]::Parse("en");
    $mco.Versioned = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings+Media]::UploadAsVersionableByDefault;
    $mco.Destination = "$($mediaPath)/$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filePath))";

    $mc = New-Object Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator
    $mc.CreateFromFile($filepath, $mco);
}

$source = "https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2020/abstractart.jpg"
$Filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($source)
$dest = "$AppPath\custom_images\$Filename"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$response = $wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest);

$images = Get-ChildItem "$AppPath\custom_images\*.jpg" -Recurse

foreach($image in $images){
    
    $imageName = $image.Name
    
    $MediaImagePath = "$AppPath\custom_images\$imageName"
    
    Write-Host $MediaImagePath
    
    #Check if the image already exists in the Media Library location.
    #If exists, skip it but log in the Sitecore log file and in the console
    #If doesn't exists, upload the image and log the message
    if(Test-Path $MediaImagePath.TrimEnd(".png"))
    {
        Write-Host "Image $imageName already exists... skipping"
    }
    else
    {       
        Write-Host "Uploading Image $imageName ..."
        
        New-MediaItem $MediaImagePath "$([Sitecore.Constants]::MediaLibraryPath)/Custom"
        
        Write-Host "Uploading Image $imageName ... done."
        
        Write-Host "Removing file $imageName"
        Remove-Item $image
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- I have created a folder on the Sitecore directory named `custom_images`. So, all downloaded images will go there. Once the uploaded is completed and successful, it will be deleted from the directory.
- This script is only targeting the `.jpg` extension. You may want to change it to a more dynamic extension filtering.
- You may need to update the name of the image when you are downloading it since special characters may be present. This will prevent the media item from being created.
- You may need to adjust the script to be more dynamic in terms of the paths.

**Result**

[image]

[image]

**References**

- [Bulk Loading Images in Sitecore Media Library Using Sitecore Powershell Extension (SPE)](https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/bulk-loading-images-in-sitecore-media-library-using-sitecore-powershell-extension-spe/)
- [Create Media Item](https://gist.github.com/AdamNaj/ad2d059c618df2fc4c03)